# Exporter for Org: can quote-block get headline's property?

Tags: org-export

With `org-export-define-backend`, I want to make `quote-block` get current headline's properties.

For example, define a function `org-my-headline(headline contents info)` for exporting `headline` , I can get the values within `:PROPERTIES:  ...  :END:` in `org-my-headline` like this:

```
(defun org-my-headline (headline contents info)
    ...
    (org-element-property :PROPERTY_NAME headline)
    ...
)
```

Now I want to define a function `org-my-quote-block(quote-block contents info)` for exporting `quote-block`, **and its behavior can be changed by current headline's property (e.g. `:QUOTE_BLOCK: hide`)**, can this task be done?

Or another way: is `#+BEGIN_QUOTE` able to get the options in title like `#+BEGIN_SRC python` can get the value `python` via `(org-element-property :language src-block)`?

*(update: the second way should be impossible...just tried `org-element-parse-buffer`, and found it will ignore all options strings in `#+BEGIN_QUOTE`)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Babel solution

Note that the value of Babel parameters can be lisp code.  Thus you can have

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :exports (if t "results") :results raw
  "\#+begin_quote 
  my quote
  \#+end_quote"
#+END_SRC
```

## Filter solution

You can easily adapt this for a derived backend.

```
(defun rasmus/get-org-string-element  (headline backend info)
"Return the org element representation of an element."
(let ((prop-point (next-property-change 0 headline)))
  (if prop-point (plist-get (text-properties-at prop-point headline) :parent))))

(defun rasmus/org-export-quotes-inherit-from-headlne (quote backend info)
  "Discard some quotes based on headline properties."
  (let* ((elm (rasmus/get-org-string-element quote backend info))
     (parent (and elm (org-export-get-parent-headline elm))))
(when (equal (org-element-property :QUOTE_BLOCK parent)
         "hide")
  "")))

(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-quote-block-functions
     'rasmus/org-export-quotes-inherit-from-headlne)
```

#### Example

```
(with-temp-buffer
  (require 'ox-org)
  (insert "
* foo
 :PROPERTIES:
 :quote_block: hide
 :END:
 bar
 \#+BEGIN_QUOTE
 bar
 \#+END_QUOTE
* foo2
 \#+BEGIN_QUOTE
 bar2
 \#+END_QUOTE")
  (org-org-export-as-org nil nil nil t))
```

Which outputs:

```
* foo
bar
* foo2
#+BEGIN_QUOTE
bar2
#+END_QUOTE
```

## Derived backend solution w/example

```
(require 'ox-org)

(org-export-define-derived-backend 'my-backend 'org
  :translate-alist '((quote-block . rasmus/org-export-quotes-inherit-from-headline)))

(defun rasmus/org-export-quotes-inherit-from-headline (quote backend info)
  "Discard some quotes based on headline properties."
  (let ((parent (org-export-get-parent-headline quote)))
(if (equal (org-element-property :QUOTE_BLOCK parent)
       "hide")
    ""
  (org-org-identity quote backend info))))

(with-temp-buffer
  (require 'ox-org)
  (insert "
* foo
 :PROPERTIES:
 :quote_block: hide
 :END:
 bar
 \#+BEGIN_QUOTE
 UNDESIRED QUOTE
 \#+END_QUOTE
* foo2
 \#+BEGIN_QUOTE
 DESIRED QUOTE
 \#+END_QUOTE")
  (org-export-to-buffer 'my-backend "*my backend export*" nil nil nil t))
```

Comment: Thaaaanks! You saved my brain's cells :D
But I found this filter applies after `org-my-quote-block`. If anyway to make the filter applies before `org-my-quote-block`; or more directly, make `org-my-quote-block` accessible to headlines' properties?

Comment: When you use it as part of a backend just skip this step `(elm (rasmus/get-org-string-element quote backend info)` since you have that element directly.

Comment: Can you explain more detailed? I still cannot understand how to "skip" this step, and what this action means...

Comment: check the new example.  it shows how to apply it to the org backend.